# Ruby: How to create a letter counting function

Tags: ruby

I wouldn't have asked for help without first spending a few hours trying to figure out my error but I'm at a wall.  So there is my attempt but I'm getting false when I try to pass the argument though and I'm not sure why.  I know there are other ways to solve this problem that are a little shorter but I'm more interested in trying to get my code to work. Any help is much appreciated.

**Write a method that takes in a string. Your method should return the most common letter in the array, and a count of how many times it appears.**

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  idx1 = 0
  idx2 = 0
  counter1 = 0
  counter2 = 0

  while idx1 < string.length
    idx2 = 0
    while idx2 < string.length
      if string[idx1] == string[idx2]
        counter1 += 1
      end
      idx2 += 1
    end
    if counter1 > counter2
      counter2 = counter1 
      counter1 = 0
      var = [string[idx1], counter2] 
    end
    idx1 += 1
  end
  return var
end

puts("most_common_letter(\"abca\") == [\"a\", 2]: #{most_common_letter("abca") == ["a", 2]}")
puts("most_common_letter(\"abbab\") == [\"b\", 3]: #{most_common_letter("abbab") == ["b", 3]}")
```

Comment: How is your code wrong?

Comment: The current letter count was only being reset if it found another letter higher but if it didn't then it wouldn't be reset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't rewrite your code because I think it's important to point out what is wrong with the existing code that you wrote (especially since you're familiar with it).  That said, there are much more 'ruby-like' ways to go about this.

#### The issue

`counter1` is only being reset if you've found a 'new highest'.  You need to reset it regardless of whether or not a new highest number has been found:

```
def most_common_letter(string)
  idx1 = 0
  idx2 = 0
  counter1 = 0
  counter2 = 0
  while idx1 < string.length
    idx2 = 0
    while idx2 < string.length
      if string[idx1] == string[idx2]
        counter1 += 1
      end
      idx2 += 1
    end
    if counter1 > counter2
      counter2 = counter1 
      # counter1 = 0  THIS IS THE ISSUE
      var = [string[idx1], counter2] 
    end
    counter1 = 0  # this is what needs to be reset each time
    idx1 += 1
  end
  return var
end
```

Here's what the output is:

```
stackoverflow master % ruby letter-count.rb
most_common_letter("abca") == ["a", 2]: true
most_common_letter("abbab") == ["b", 3]: true
```

I think you're aware there are way better ways to do this but frankly the best way to debug this is with a piece of paper.  "Ok counter1 is now 1, indx2 is back to zero", etc.  That will help you keep track.

Another bit of advice, `counter1` and `counter2` are not very good variable names.  I didn't realize what you were using them for initially and that should never be the case, it should be named something like `current_count` `highest_known_count` or something like that.

Comment: I appreciate the help a lot and definitely work it out on paper completely next time. Thanks again.

Comment: Upvote for fixing the problem with the given solution without "doing their homework for them' by offering a " better" solution.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has been answered and @theTinMan has suggested a more Ruby-like way of doing what you want to do.  There are many other ways of doing this and you might find it useful to consider a couple more.

Let's use the string:

```
string = "Three blind mice. Oh! See how they run."
```

First, you need to answer a couple of questions:

- do you want the frequency of letters or characters?
- do you want the frequency of lowercase and uppercase letters combined?

I assume you want the frequency of letters only, independent of case.

**#1 Count each unique letter**

We can deal with the case issue by converting all the letters to lower or upper case, using the method [String#upcase](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-upcase) or [String#downcase](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-downcase):

```
s1 = string.downcase
  #=> "three blind mice. oh! see how they run."
```

Next we need to get rid of all the characters that are not letters. For that, we can use [String#delete](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-delete)<sup>1</sup>:

```
s2 = s1.delete('^a-z')
  #=> "threeblindmiceohseehowtheyrun"
```

Now we are ready to convert the string `s2` to an an array of individual characters<sup>2</sup>:

```
arr = s2.chars
  #=> ["t", "h", "r", "e", "e", "b", "l", "i", "n", "d",
  #    "m", "i", "c", "e", "o", "h", "s", "e", "e", "h",
  #    "o", "w", "t", "h", "e", "y", "r", "u", "n"]
```

We can combine these first three steps as follows:

```
arr = string.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '').chars
```

First obtain all the distinct letters present, using [Array.uniq](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

```
arr1 = arr.uniq
  #=> ["t", "h", "r", "e", "b", "l", "i", "n",
  #    "d", "m", "c", "o", "s", "w", "y", "u"]
```

Now convert each of these characters to a two-character array consisting of the letter and its count in `arr`.  Whenever you need convert elements of a collection to something else, think [Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) (a.k.a. `collect`). The counting is done with [Array#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-count). We have:

```
arr2 = arr1.map { |c| [c, arr.count(c)] }
  #=> [["t", 2], ["h", 4], ["r", 2], ["e", 6], ["b", 1], ["l", 1],
  #    ["i", 2], ["n", 2], ["d", 1], ["m", 1], ["c", 1], ["o", 2],
  #    ["s", 1], ["w", 1], ["y", 1], ["u", 1]]
```

Lastly, we use [Enumerable#max_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) to extract the element of `arr2` with the largest count<sup>3</sup>:

```
arr2.max_by(&:last)
  #=> ["e", 6]
```

We can combine the calculation of `arr1` and `arr2`:

```
arr.uniq.map { |c| [c, arr.count(c)] }.max_by(&:last)
```

and further replace `arr` with that obtained earlier:

```
string.downcase.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '').chars.uniq.map { |c|
  [c, arr.count(c)] }.max_by(&:last)
  #=> ["e", 6]
```

[String#chars](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-chars) returns a temporary array, upon which the method [Array#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq) is invoked. As alternative, which avoids the creation of the temporary array, is to use [String#each_char](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-each_char) in place of `String#chars`, which returns an enumerator, upon which [Enumerable#uniq](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-uniq) is invoked.

The use of `Array#count` is quite an inefficient way to do the counting  because a full pass through `arr` is made for each unique letter. The methods below are much more efficient.

**#2 Use a hash**

With this approach we wish to create a hash whose keys are the distinct elements of `arr` and each value is the count of the associated key. Begin by using the class method [Hash::new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) to create hash whose values have a default value of zero:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
  #=> {}
```

We now do the following:

```
string.each_char { |c| h[c.downcase] += 1 if c =~ /[a-z]/i }
h #=> {"t"=>2, "h"=>4, "r"=>2, "e"=>6, "b"=>1, "l"=>1, "i"=>2, "n"=>2,
  #    "d"=>1, "m"=>1, "c"=>1, "o"=>2, "s"=>1, "w"=>1, "y"=>1, "u"=>1}
```

Recall `h[c] += 1` is shorthand for:

```
h[c] = h[c] + 1
```

If the hash does not already have a key `c` when the above expression is evaluated, `h[c]` on the right side is replaced by the default value of zero.

Since the `Enumerable` module is included in the class `Hash` we can invoke `max_by` on `h` just as we did on the array:

```
h.max_by(&:last)
  #=> ["e", 6]
```

There is just one more step. Using [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object), we can shorten this as follows:

```
string.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c,h|
  h[c.downcase] += 1 if c =~ /[a-z]/i
end.max_by(&:last)
  #=> ["e", 6]
```

The argument of `each_with_object` is an object we provide (the empty hash with default zero). This is represented by the additional block variable `h`. The expression

```
string.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |c,h|
  h[c.downcase] += 1 if c =~ /[a-z]/i
end
```

returns `h`, to which `max_by(&:last)` is sent.

**#3 Use `group_by`**

I will give a slightly modified version of the Tin Man's answer and show how it works with the value of `string` I have used. It uses the method [Enumerable#group_by](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
letters = string.downcase.delete('^a-z').each_char.group_by { |c| c }
  #=> {"t"=>["t", "t"], "h"=>["h", "h", "h", "h"], "r"=>["r", "r"],
  #    "e"=>["e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e"], "b"=>["b"], "l"=>["l"],
  #    "i"=>["i", "i"], "n"=>["n", "n"], "d"=>["d"], "m"=>["m"],
  #    "c"=>["c"], "o"=>["o", "o"], "s"=>["s"], "w"=>["w"],
  #    "y"=>["y"], "u"=>["u"]}

used_most = letters.max_by { |k,v| v.size }
  #=> ["e", ["e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e"]]
used_most[1] = used_most[1].size
used_most
  #=> ["e", 6]
```

In later versions of Ruby you could simplify as follows:

```
string.downcase.delete('^a-z').each_char.group_by(&:itself).
       transform_values(&:size).max_by(&:last)
  #=> ["e", 6]
```

See [Enumerable#max_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by), [Object#itself](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-itself) and [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

<sup>1. Alternatively, use [String#gsub](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-gsub): `s1.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '')`.</sup>

<sup>2. `s2.split('')` could also be used.</sup>

<sup>3. More or less equivalent to `arr2.max_by { |c, count| count }`.</sup>

Comment: With that many options, and that many varying efficiencies it'd be good to show a benchmark, otherwise the OP will pick one that isn't necessary fast, or that will rapidly slow down as the string size increases.

Answer (score 3):

It's a problem you'll find asked all over Stack Overflow, a quick search should have returned a number of hits.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
foo = 'abacab'
letters = foo.chars.group_by{ |c| c }

used_most = letters.sort_by{ |k, v| [v.size, k] }.last
used_most # => ["a", ["a", "a", "a"]]
puts '"%s" was used %d times' % [used_most.first, used_most.last.size]
# >> "a" was used 3 times
```

Of course, now that this is here, and it's easily found, you can't use it because any teacher worth listening to will also know how to search Stack Overflow and will find this answer.

Comment: Ah yeah I wasn't sure what to search to find others like this and was also looking to fix my code specifically. And the tutorial I went over before the assigned problems didn't go over methods like that but I'll definitely learn the ones you mentioned.